# Entering If Statement Despite Not Meeting Condition

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is a specific problem, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

```
else if (X == 2)
        //move left
    {
        if (Level[X-1][Y] == 0);
        {

            cout << Level[X-1][Y] << "\n";
            cout << "\n MOVING LEFT from RIGHT\n";  //PROBLEM IS HERE

            Level[X][Y] = 1; // block it
            X = X - 1;
            moved = 1;
        }
    }
```

What I am doing is I am checking if Level[X-1][Y] is 1, indicating a column, so I can not move my player there. However for some reason, despite it being 1 and not 0 (as indicated by the output), the IF statement is still accessed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think compilers can warn about this ([*and I was right*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b27d75968d98eb0b)).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would it enter if the statement is false? My G++ compiler isnt giving any warnings either.

Comment: First, look at the warning message in the link. It's pretty clear. Secondly, add the warning options shown in the link's command line and I'm sure you will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Semi-colon!!!

```
   if (Level[X-1][Y] == 0);
```

Comment: Can you explain to the OP what the semicolon means?

Comment: wooopsies. Thanks a lot, silly question on my part, spent hours on this!!

Comment: @msmf14 - you're not the first to get hung up on something like this. Eventually, checking for that accidental semi-colon becomes automatic. Until then it can be very frustrating.

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is here:

```
if (Level[X-1][Y] == 0);
                       ^
```

the `;` ends the *if* statement. What follows the *if* statement is just a *compound statement* like this:

```
{
  //Code
}
```

and are completely valid on their own and have many uses, one use of which is creating a *block scope*.

For completeness sake if we go to the draft [C++ standard section](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) `6.2` *Expression Statements* we see that the `;`  just terminates a *null statement*. The grammar is as follows:

```
expression-statement:
  expressionopt ;
                ^
```

and it also says:

> [...]An expression statement with the expression missing is called a null statement.[...]

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Level[X-1][Y] == 0);
//                     ^
```

Get rid of this semicolon.

It would make the logic like this: if `Level[X-1][Y]` is zero, do nothing, then run the following code(the compound statement you thought was belong to the `if`). It's equivalent to:

```
if (Level[X-1][Y] == 0)
{
    ;
}
{
    cout << Level[X-1][Y] << "\n";
    cout << "\n MOVING LEFT from RIGHT\n";
    Level[X][Y] = 1;
    X = X - 1;
    moved = 1;
}
```