# Can anyone make heads or tales of this spigot algorithm code Pitiny.c

Tags: c, compression, pi, lossless-compression, spigot-algorithm

This *C* program is just 143 characters long!

But it “decompresses” into the first 10,000 digits of *Pi*.

```
//  Created by cheeseMan on 30/11/13.

long a[35014],b,c=35014,d,e,f=1e4,g,h;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])

{
    for(;(b=c-=14);

        h=printf("%04ld",e+d/f))

        for(e=d%=f;(g=--b*2);d/=g)
            d=d*b+f*(h?a[b]:f/5), a[b]=d%--g;
}
```

I was doing some  research on loss-less compression algorithms, still no luck yet, when I came across this `pitiny.c`.

The weird thing is  that it compiles  successfully no errors or bugs, but like i said i cannot make heads or tales of the code, even its syntax. I just would like to know whats going on? what is it doing exactly?

Comment: See [Spigot algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm).

Comment: This is a demo of how to write code in very few incomprehensible  lines, a "parlor trick". It is a mathematical routine, not a compression method.

Comment: While searching for lossless decompression code, you came across this an an example? Writing out π has nothing to do with any compression. Do you remember where it was stated it does?

Comment: As an aside, there is an overall error in the code, several of the variables are not initialized to 0. This may work in `main()` but will knot work reliably in a function. I know this because I tried!

Comment: Does the routine fail to generate valid pi digits with more interactions?

Comment: @chux I created two functions, executed each and compared the output so I could be sure I was not breaking the code. The second execution failed miserable. Notice that d & e are used prior to initialization. "C" does not guarantee zeroed automatics in functions.

Comment: @Jongware Interesting about "Writing out π has nothing to do with any compression".  One way to write π is "π".  Another is "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089 ..."   This program appears to be  a third way. :-)

Comment: @chux: if one classifies calculating pi as "decompression" then *any* algorithm is going to be a lossy one, per definition of pi as "irrational". Very interesting stuff, though. I wonder if the OP got anything useful out of it (wrt. his compression research, that is).

Comment: @zaph: All of the variables are globals, which are [automatically initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091499/why-are-global-and-static-variables-initialized-to-their-default-values) to 0 unless initialized with another value (they get put in the BSS section).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**

This program is a purposely obfuscated implementation of a [spigot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm) algorithm [for the Digits of Pi](https://web.archive.org/web/20160825213515/http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/spigot.pdf) from the book *Pi - Unleashed* and we can find the original version on [page 37 of the book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=QwwcmweJCDQC&pg=PA37&source=gbs_toc_r&redir_esc=y&hl=nl#v=onepage&q&f=false) which is as follows:

> a[52514],b,c=52514,d,e,f=1e4,g,h;main(){for(;b=c-=14;h=printf("%04d",
>   e+d/f))for(e=d%=f;g=--b*2;d/=g)d=d*b+f*(h?a[b]:f/5),a[b]=d%--g;}

the paper [Unbounded Spigot Algorithms for the Digits of Pi](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf) does a good job in explaining the algorithm. Basically it is an implementation of this expansion:

[image: formula]

**Original**

The reason it was designed this way other than to make the code impossible to comprehend and impress people escapes me but we can break down what is going on, first here:

```
long a[35014],b,c=35014,d,e,f=1e4,g,h;
```

the variables are *static* since they are global so all variables not explicitly initialized will be initialized to `0`. Next we have an outer *for loop*:

```
for(;(b=c-=14); h=printf("%04ld",e+d/f)
    ^ ^         ^
    1 2         3
```

1. Is an empty initialization and it also a [null statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507247/entering-if-statement-despite-not-meeting-condition/19507325#19507325).
2. Is subtracting `14` from `c` and assigning the value back to `c` and also assigning the same value to `b`. This loop will execute `2500` times since `35014/14` is 2501 and on the `2501`th iteration the result will `0` and thus *false* and the loop will stop.
3. `h` is being assigned the result of `printf` which is the number of characters printed. What is being printed out is the result of `e+d/f` and always at least 4 digits and zero padded due to `04` in the *format specifier*.

Now we have an inner *for loop*:

```
for(e=d%=f;(g=--b*2);d/=g)
    ^       ^        ^
    1       2        3
```

1. Initializes `e` and `d` to `d modulus f`.
2. Due to [operator precedence](https://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) does a *pre-decrement* of `b` and multiples that by `2` and assigns the result to `g`
3. `d` is being divided by `g` and assigned the result.

Finally the body of the inner for loop:

```
d=d*b+f*(h?a[b]:f/5), a[b]=d%--g;
          ^         ^
          1         2
```

uses both the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C) in `1` and [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in `2`. So we could at least split this into:

```
d    = d*b+f*(h?a[b]:f/5) ; // (1)
a[b] = d%--g;               // (2)
```

`(1)` can further be broken down into:

```
long tmp =  h ? a[b] : f/5 ;  // conditional operator
d = (d * b) + f * tmp;
```

The conditional operator only matters during the first iteration since `h` is intialized to `0` but will never be `0` again afterwards since it is always assigned a non-zero value in the outer *for loop*, so other then the first time `h` will be assigned `a[b]`.

`(2)` will again due to precedence pre-decrement `g` first and then evaluate `d` modulus the result and assign that to `a[b]`.

Comment: Very nice explanation! I would love to see a nicely refactored version.

Comment: @Zaph let me try and get the formatting improved some and add links and such and I will attempt that.

Comment: Consider writing out the ternary in full, it's kind of hidden now. As for those predecrements .. (reading the original *again*) okay, those *are* significant.

Comment: @Shafik I have refactored it and added an answer.

Comment: @Zaph +1 I did not get enough time to complete the process but what you have is pretty similar to what I was getting to.

Answer (score 2):

It can be written as

```
long a[35014];
long b;
long c=35014;
long d;
long e;
long f=1e4;
long g;
long h;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(; (b=c-=14); h=printf("%04ld",e+d/f)) {
        for(e=d%=f; (g=--b*2); d/=g) {
            d = (d * b) + f * ( h ? a[b] : f/5);
            a[b] = d % --g;
        }
    }
}
```

In other words it's double `for` loop

Comment: The code could be made substantially more simple, this only separates the vars and does not make the code any more comprehensible, infact making the code more dense by moving the printf inside a for loop.

Comment: @Zaph, the `printf` was already inside a `for` loop. Now that the code is clearer, you easily notice it. Of course, it can be made much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Just for grins:
"Calculate" Pi to 10,000 digits
Here is a "simplified" version. "Simplified" meaning breaking up the multiple operators, using the results of assignment statements and for loops. Missing are meaningful names.

(this was verified against the results of the original code.

```
void simplier() {
    long a[35014];
    long b = 0;
    long c = 35000;
    long d = 0;
    long e = 0;
    long f = 10000;
    long g = 0;
    long h = 0;
    long i = 0;

    while (c) {
        d %= f;
        e  = d;
        b  = c-1;
        g  = b*2;

        while(g) {
            g -= 1;
            i  = h ? a[b] : f/5;
            d  = (d*b) + (f*i);
            a[b] = d % g;
            d /= g;
            b -= 1;
            g  = b*2;
        }

        printf("%04ld", e+d/f);
        h  = 1;
        c -= 14;
    }
}
```

Runtimes:

> Original time: 1.110
>   Simplier time: 1.138

Of course most of the time is in the formatting and printing.

Output:

> 3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952035301852968995773622599413891249721775283479131515574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319255060400927701671139009848824012858361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534646208046684259069491293313677028989152104752162056966024058038150193511253382430035587640247496473263914199272604269922796782354781636009341721641219924586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955321165344987202755960236480665499119881834797753566369807426542527862551818417574672890977772793800081647060016145249192173217214772350141441973568548161361157352552133475741849468438523323907394143334547762416862518983569485562099219222184272550254256887671790494601653466804988627232791786085784383827967976681454100953883786360950680064225125205117392984896084128488626945604241965285022210661186306744278622039194945047123713786960956364371917287467764657573962413890865832645995813390478027590099465764078951269468398352595709825822620522489407726719478268482601476990902640136394437455305068203496252451749399651431429809190659250937221696461515709858387410597885959772975498930161753928468138268683868942774155991855925245953959431049972524680845987273644695848653836736222626099124608051243884390451244136549762780797715691435997700129616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506016842739452267467678895252138522549954666727823986456596116354886230577456498035593634568174324112515076069479451096596094025228879710893145669136867228748940560101503308617928680920874760917824938589009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998948722658804857564014270477555132379641451523746234364542858444795265867821051141354735739523113427166102135969536231442952484937187110145765403590279934403742007310578539062198387447808478489683321445713868751943506430218453191048481005370614680674919278191197939952061419663428754440643745123718192179998391015919561814675142691239748940907186494231961567945208095146550225231603881930142093762137855956638937787083039069792077346722182562599661501421503068038447734549202605414665925201497442850732518666002132434088190710486331734649651453905796268561005508106658796998163574736384052571459102897064140110971206280439039759515677157700420337869936007230558763176359421873125147120532928191826186125867321579198414848829164470609575270695722091756711672291098169091528017350671274858322287183520935396572512108357915136988209144421006751033467110314126711136990865851639831501970165151168517143765761835155650884909989859982387345528331635507647918535893226185489632132933089857064204675259070915481416549859461637180270981994309924488957571282890592323326097299712084433573265489382391193259746366730583604142813883032038249037589852437441702913276561809377344403070746921120191302033038019762110110044929321516084244485963766983895228684783123552658213144957685726243344189303968642624341077322697802807318915441101044682325271620105265227211166039666557309254711055785376346682065310989652691862056476931257058635662018558100729360659876486117910453348850346113657686753249441668039626579787718556084552965412665408530614344431858676975145661406800700237877659134401712749470420562230538994561314071127000407854733269939081454664645880797270826683063432858785698305235808933065757406795457163775254202114955761581400250126228594130216471550979259230990796547376125517656751357517829666454779174501129961489030463994713296210734043751895735961458901938971311179042978285647503203198691514028708085990480109412147221317947647772622414254854540332157185306142288137585043063321751829798662237172159160771669254748738986654949450114654062843366393790039769265672146385306736096571209180763832716641627488880078692560290228472104031721186082041900042296617119637792133757511495950156604963186294726547364252308177036751590673502350728354056704038674351362222477158915049530984448933309634087807693259939780541934144737744184263129860809988868741326047215695162396586457302163159819319516735381297416772947867242292465436680098067692823828068996400482435403701416314965897940924323789690706977942236250822168895738379862300159377647165122893578601588161755782973523344604281512627203734314653197777416031990665541876397929334419521541341899485444734567383162499341913181480927777103863877343177207545654532207770921201905166096280490926360197598828161332316663652861932668633606273567630354477628035045077723554710585954870279081435624014517180624643626794561275318134078330336254232783944975382437205835311477119926063813346776879695970309833913077109870408591337464144282277263465947047458784778720192771528073176790770715721344473060570073349243693113835049316312840425121925651798069411352801314701304781643788518529092854520116583934196562134914341595625865865570552690496520985803385072242648293972858478316305777756068887644624824685792603953527734803048029005876075825104747091643961362676044925627420420832085661190625454337213153595845068772460290161876679524061634252257719542916299193064553779914037340432875262888963995879475729174642635745525407909145135711136941091193932519107602082520261879853188770584297259167781314969900901921169717372784768472686084900337702424291651300500516832336435038951702989392233451722013812806965011784408745196012122859937162313017114448464090389064495444006198690754851602632750529834918740786680881833851022833450850486082503930213321971551843063545500766828294930413776552793975175461395398468339363830474611996653858153842056853386218672523340283087112328278921250771262946322956398989893582116745627010218356462201349671518819097303811980049734072396103685406643193950979019069963955245300545058068550195673022921913933918568034490398205955100226353536192041994745538593810234395544959778377902374216172711172364343543947822181852862408514006660443325888569867054315470696574745855033232334210730154594051655379068662733379958511562578432298827372319898757141595781119635833005940873068121602876496286744604774649159950549737425626901049037781986835938146574126804925648798556145372347867330390468838343634655379498641927056387293174872332083760112302991136793862708943879936201629515413371424892830722012690147546684765357616477379467520049075715552781965362132392640616013635815590742202020318727760527721900556148425551879253034351398442532234157623361064250639049750086562710953591946589751413103482276930624743536325691607815478181152843667957061108615331504452127473924544945423682886061340841486377670096120715124914043027253860764823634143346235189757664521641376796903149501910857598442391986291642193994907236234646844117394032659184044378051333894525742399508296591228508555821572503107125701266830240292952522011872676756220415420516184163484756516999811614101002996078386909291603028840026910414079288621507842451670908700069928212066041837180653556725253256753286129104248776182582976515795984703562226293486003415872298053498965022629174878820273420922224533985626476691490556284250391275771028402799806636582548892648802545661017296702664076559042909945681506526530537182941270336931378517860904070866711496558343434769338578171138645587367812301458768712660348913909562009939361031029161615288138437909904231747336394804575931493140529763475748119356709110137751721008031559024853090669203767192203322909433467685142214477379393751703443661991040337511173547191855046449026365512816228824462575916333039107225383742182140883508657391771509682887478265699599574490661758344137522397096834080053559849175417381883999446974867626551658276584835884531427756879002909517028352971634456212964043523117600665101241200659755851276178583829204197484423608007193045761893234922927965019875187212726750798125547095890455635792122103334669749923563025494780249011419521238281530911407907386025152274299581807247162591668545133312394804947079119153267343028244186041426363954800044800267049624820179289647669758318327131425170296923488962766844032326092752496035799646925650493681836090032380929345958897069536534940603402166544375589004563288225054525564056448246515187547119621844396582533754388569094113031509526179378002974120766514793942590298969594699556576121865619673378623625612521632086286922210327488921865436480229678070576561514463204692790682120738837781423356282360896320806822246801224826117718589638140918390367367222088832151375560037279839400415297002878307667094447456013455641725437090697939612257142989467154357846878861444581231459357198492252847160504922124247014121478057345510500801908699603302763478708108175450119307141223390866393833952942578690507643100638351983438934159613185434754649556978103829309716465143840700707360411237359984345225161050702705623526601276484830840761183013052793205427462865403603674532865105706587488225698157936789766974220575059683440869735020141020672358502007245225632651341055924019027421624843914035998953539459094407046912091409387001264560016237428802109276457931065792295524988727584610126483699989225695968815920560010165525637567

Comment: Nice format. It does show why well-formatted code is so much easier to understand.

Comment: The use of `h` is still obfuscated: it's just a flag for "first loop", the fact that it gets filled with the printf result (which is always 4) is irrelevant. `i` can then be initialized to `f/5`, and the line `i=..` needs moving down one line.

Comment: @Jongware While `h` is just used a flag it is not set to non-zero until after the inner loop completes once so `i` can not be set to `a[b]` in the inner loop as you suggest. I did update the code to explicitly use `h` as a flag.

Comment: Zaph, you sure? The first time around, `h=0` and `i` is assigned `f/5` (`f` is a constant). All next loops, `i` get assigned `a[b]`. The new value of `i` gets used in the *next* line so that's why I suggested moving it a line down.

Comment: @Jongware `h` is not set until after the inner loops completes once, not after the first iteration of the inner loop. Fir the first run of the inner loop `i` has to be `f/5`, after that I is `a[b]`. I am sure, I have a test (always do for refactoring) that runs the original code and the refactored code. Try the code, all you need to look at are the last 4 digits to see the problem.

Comment: Ah, got it, I missed the first round through the inner loop. Thx for clarifying!