# Can not understand this pi calculate algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I saw a pi calculate algorithm on a website and it looks like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[52514],b,c=52514,d,e,f=1e4,g,h;
main(){
 for(;b=c-=14;h=printf("%04d",e+d/f)){
    for(e=d%=f;g=--b*2;d/=g){
        d=d*b+f*(h?a[b]:f/5);
        a[b]=d%--g;}
   }
}
```

it was said this code was based on this expansion,but i do not understand the relative between the code and the expansion.

> pi= sigma( (i!) ^2*2^(i+1))/(2i+1)!
>   (i=0 to infinite)

Could you help me explain it?Thanks.

Comment: throw in a macro or two and you have an IOCCC winner, if not already.

Comment: @Plopperzz so what is macro means?and what should I do?

Comment: take a look at this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287513/can-anyone-make-heads-or-tales-of-this-spigot-algorithm-code-pitiny-c), which also mentions the [Spigot Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm).  funny, I was the 314th viewer of that post.

Comment: @Plopperzz thanks,it is really hard to understand.

Comment: @Plopperzz Now I know how the code run,but I can not understand why it equals to the expansion.i think there is no reason it print the digits of pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pi+3=sigma( (m!)^2 * 2^m * m / (2*m)! ) (m=1 to infinite).
```

Algorithm's S Pflouffe use it.

Comment: But I still can not understand why this code is equal to the expansion.